# how to convert long to byte array in java?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have made `long` value from byte array using this code

```
byte[] by = {07, 53 -70, 74};

long value = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < by.length; i++) {
    value =  ((value << 8) + (by[i] & 0xff));
}

System.out.println(value);
```

out put is `520010`

now I want reverse process on this and I tried it this way

```
long ts = 520010;

tm_stp[0] = (byte) ((byte) ts>>24);
tm_stp[1] = (byte) ((byte) ts>>16);
tm_stp[2] = (byte) ((byte) ts>>8);
tm_stp[3] = (byte) ts;
for (byte b : tm_stp) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

and output is `0 0 0 74`

what is wrong in my second part of code please help me, Thanks!

Comment: A long is 64 bits in Java, so it's 8 bytes - not 4 bytes as you assume in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fact that you cast to `byte` too early:

```
tm_stp[0] = (byte) ((byte) ts>>24);
tm_stp[1] = (byte) ((byte) ts>>16);
tm_stp[2] = (byte) ((byte) ts>>8);
                   //^^^^
```

This causes the `ts` value to be truncated, replacing the first 24 bytes with `0`s. After that, shifting by anything greater than or equal to 8 will return `0`. To avoid incorrect behaviour with negative values, you should also use a bitmask. The correct code should look like this:

```
tm_stp[0] = (byte) ((ts >> 24) & 0xFF);
tm_stp[1] = (byte) ((ts >> 16) & 0xFF);
tm_stp[2] = (byte) ((ts >>  8) & 0xFF);
tm_stp[3] = (byte) ((ts >>  0) & 0xFF); // >> 0 not actually required, only for symmetry
```

Comment: doing this `tm_stp[3] = (byte) ts;
  tm_stp[2] = (byte) (ts >> 8);
  tm_stp[1] = (byte) (ts >> 16);
  tm_stp[0] = (byte) (ts >> 24);` output is `0
7
-17
74` not actual

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert `ts` to `byte` before shifting.

```
tm_stp[0] = (byte) (ts >> 24);
tm_stp[1] = (byte) (ts >> 16);
tm_stp[2] = (byte) (ts >> 8);
tm_stp[3] = (byte) ts;
```